# Why the Android-Emulator always returns a 'connection timed out' when running a flutter dart file

Tags: flutter, android-studio, emulation

I was ran a Flutter file on Android Studio (Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2) to test fetch data from api.openai.com. Using a emulator of Nexus 6 API 28. The Flutter version 3.7.8.

The codes running on localhost well, but it always got a 'connection timed out' message a emulator returned.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'),

    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiKey',
    },
    body: jsonEncode({
      "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",

      "messages": [
        {
          "role": "user",
          "content": '$prompt',
        }
      ]
    }),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }

}


class Album{ ... }    //details ominatted


void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
  String prompt = 'hello';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data from OpenAi',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data from OpenAi'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('object' + snapshot.data!.object),
                    Text('id: ' + snapshot.data!.id),
                    Text('created' + snapshot.data!.created.toString()),
                    Text('content: ' + snapshot.data!.content)
                  ],
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Are there people met same issue and would you please share your experience here? Tank you very much!

Comment: You already verified if this host is reachable through your simulator device?

Comment: Yes, it exactly retuned me the contents. I used the dart_openai 1.9.0 API and ran on device of Chrome.